# How do I connect a database to an Android app?

Tags: android, android-database

I am new to Android development and I am working on building an app. I am currently stuck on the log-in screen because there are no up to date tutorials that can walk me step by step into creating and linking a database.

I would like to have a database so that when the register button is pressed, the information is stored into a database.

I currently only have activity_main.xml and MainActivity.kt, the basics of creating a blank activity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. There are a number of learning references at the bottom of the [android tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info). Also be aware of [JDBC vs Web Service for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15853367/295004). Regardless, StackOverflow is for specific programming questions where the poster shows code/effort. General  questions such as looking for tutorials are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

There are up to date tutorials for everything if you just do a quick google search. There are a number of different techniques. Here are a few `up to date` things provided by Google that I will encourage you to learn and experiment with:
[Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)
[Android Room with a View - Kotlin](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0)
[Using Room Database | Android Jetpack](https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-android-jetpack-675a89a0e942)